# Kickstarter支援者向けに、サーバーを使わずアプリの限定アイテムを配布することは可能でしょうか？

Tags: android, unity3d

Kickstarter支援者に、特別アイテムをプレゼントしたいのですが

Androidアプリ、(Unity3d制作)で
サーバーを立ててユーザー認証をする方法ではなく、
アプリ単体でどの支援者か判別する方法はあるでしょうか？

支援者に特別アイテム用のパスワードをメールで送る
などは考えたのですが、
それだとパスワードをTwitterなどでつぶやかれたり、
攻略サイトに張られたりなどされる可能性もあり
スマートな方法ではないと考えます。

サーバー立てないのは、単に僕がサーバー触ったことないだけなので
他に方法がなければそのままパスワード制にするか
この機会にサーバーの勉強を始めようかと思うのですが。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
確かにアプリを解析されたらどうにもならないですね。
皆様の意見でアプリ内だけでどうにかしようと手間ひまかけるより、
サーバー扱う方法を覚えたほうが早いように思えました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サーバーを使わない -> アプリ内に配布したいアイテム情報がある -> 逆アセンブルをすれば（時間が多少かかるかもですが）その情報は見つかる

となるので、サーバーで何らかの認証の仕組みが必要になると思います。

最近は自分でサーバーを構築せずに使えるサービス（MBaaS）があるので、それを利用するのがてっとり早い気がします。

http://jp-cloud.kii.com/
http://www.appiaries.com/jp/baas/
http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/about.htm

Answer (score 1):

あらかじめ必要になったキーを全て製品に埋め込んで、漏えいしたものはアップデートを通してブラックリスト化するという手がありますが、漏れるとすれば、解析を通して全てのキーが漏れていき、大変でしょうね。他に思いつく方法に以下があります。

- 支援者向けのプライベートなWebページで毎回のアップデート毎に変わるキーを配布し続ける
- 支援者向けの別のビルドが入手できる配布ページを設ける

どちらも、手間がかかるのには変わりなさそうです。

支援者らは、ビジネスライクな対応を求めておられないでしょうから、支援者がそれほど多くない場合は、情報を伝達するプライベートページは Google Doc 等のオンラインサービスを使用してもいいかもしれません。

**補足:**

Kickstarter サイトには、支援者を判別できるような公開APIがありませんが、内製アプリ向けの[プライベートAPI](https://api.kickstarter.com)が存在し、それを利用した[クライアントライブラリ](https://github.com/wolfbyte/Kickstarter.Api)を [NuGet で利用可能](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kickstarter.Api/1.0.0)です。ただし、これは非公式なものであり、いつAPIが変更されるかわかりません。

参考: [Let's Explore Kickstarter's API](http://syntaxi.net/2013/03/24/let-s-explore-kickstarter-s-api/)

Answer (score 1):

どちらも使った事が無いので、Unity3dでどこまで作り込み可能か判りません 
ですので認証の手法だけですが…

> 支援者に特別アイテム用のパスワードをメールで送る

この部分からユーザーのメールアドレスが判明していると仮定するのであれば  
メールの認証を利用して本人確認する手段が有ります。

1．支援者にメールでアプリに入力するコードを配信

・コード内容は秘密鍵で暗号化して以下のものを送る  
 個別の支援者のメールアドレス  
 特典アイテムを特定するためのコードや/認証等

2．アプリに送られたコードを入力

・アプリ側で以下の処理を行う  
 受け取ったコードを公開鍵で復号化  
 アプリ固有のパスを新規に生成・保存(このパスは他の端末では使用不可能)  
 復号化したメールアドレス宛にアプリ固有のパスをアプリ内から直接送信  
 (送信に端末内のメーラーは使わない事)

3．受信したメール記載のパスがアプリ内保持のパスと一致するかで認証

サーバーを建てられるなら2の後半に追加の認証処理(暗号/復号化等)と  
サーバー側で保持したアドレスにメール送信をする事でコードの短縮化や  
セキュリティの向上も見込めますね。